# How to extract leaf nodes from Oracle XMLTYPE

Tags: oracle, xpath, extract, xmltype

I want to extract only the leaf nodes from an XMLTYPE object in Oracle 10g

```
SELECT
    t.getStringVal() AS text
FROM
    TABLE( XMLSequence( 
        XMLTYPE(
            '<xml>
                <node>
                    <one>text</one>
                </node>
                <node>
                    <two>text</two>
                </node>
                <node>
                    <three>text</three>
                </node>
            </xml>'
        ).extract( '//*' ) 
    ) ) t
```

What should I use as the WHERE clause so this returns only these:

```
                    <one>text</one>
                    <two>text</two>
                    <three>text</three>
```

I've tried the following but they don't work:

```
WHERE t.existsNode( '//*' ) = 0
WHERE t.existsNode( '/.//*' ) = 0
WHERE t.existsNode( './/*' ) = 0
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found it:

```
WHERE
    t.existsNode( '/*//*' ) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The XPath `//*[not(*)]` will get any element at level 1 or deeper that does not have any children:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/61)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t.getStringVal()
FROM   TABLE(
         XMLSEQUENCE(
           XMLTYPE(
             '<xml>
             <node><one>text</one></node>
             <node><two>text</two></node>
             <node><three>text</three></node>
             </xml>'
           ).extract( '//*[not(*)]' )
         )
       ) t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/61/0)**:

```
|    T.GETSTRINGVAL() |
|---------------------|
|     <one>text</one> |
|     <two>text</two> |
| <three>text</three> |
```

If you want to be able to include the root element then use the XPath  `(//*|/*)[not(*)]`

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following PL/SQL:

```
DECLARE
  x XMLType := XMLType(
            '<?xml version="1.0" ?>
            <xml>
                <node>
                    <one>text</one>
                </node>
                <node>
                    <two>text</two>
                </node
                <node>
                    <three>text</three>
                </node>
            </xml>');
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (
    SELECT ExtractValue(Value(p),'/XML/node/one/text()') as one_x
          ,ExtractValue(Value(p),'/XML/node/two/text()') as TWO_x
          ,ExtractValue(Value(p),'/XML/node/three/text()') as three
    FROM   TABLE(XMLSequence(Extract(x,'/XML/node/'))) p
    ) LOOP
    /* do whatever you want with r.one_x, r.TWO_x, r.three_x */
  END LOOP;
END;
```